# Change key value when button click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying save data to localstorage when button clicked. But when I click the button key always 0 and I update record,dont create new record because key = 0. I tryed increment key value throught closures but I'm very new in JS and my "return" doesn't work.
(

```
function() {

    window.onload = function() {
        var key = 0;
        document.getElementById('buttonCreate').onclick = function() {
            var topicValue = document.getElementById("create-topic").value;
            var statusValue = document.getElementById("create-status").value;
            var descriptionValue = document.getElementById("create-description").value;


            var storage = new Storage();
            var ticket = {
                topic: topicValue,
                status: statusValue,
                description: descriptionValue
            };
            storage.set(key, ticket);
            return (function() {

                return ++key;

            }());
        }
    }
})();
function Storage() {
  this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR = 'items';
}
Storage.prototype.get = function() {
  var fromStorage = localStorage.getItem(this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR);
  return fromStorage ? JSON.parse(fromStorage) : [];
};
Storage.prototype.set = function(key, items) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(items));
};
```

Comment: Why does `set` take use the given key, but `get` always uses `_ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR`? How do you retrieve the items you saved with `set`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `key` outside the `onclick` function, otherwise it gets set back to 0 every time you click. You don't need to do the increment in an internal function.

There's also no need to create a new `Storage` every time you click, you can create that once at the beginning as well.

```
function() {
    var key = 0;
    var storage = new Storage();
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('buttonCreate').onclick = function() {
            var topicValue = document.getElementById("create-topic").value;
            var statusValue = document.getElementById("create-status").value;
            var descriptionValue = document.getElementById("create-description").value;

            var ticket = {
                topic: topicValue,
                status: statusValue,
                description: descriptionValue
            };
            storage.set(key, ticket);
            key++;
        }
    }
})();
```